# If $(\alpha,\beta)$ is the factor pair congruences of algebra $\mathbb{A},$ ia $(\forall \gamma\in ConA)\alpha\circ\gamma=\gamma\circ\beta?$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, lattice-orders, universal-algebra, congruence-relations

Let $\mathbb{A}$ be an algebra such that $ConA$ is the distributive lattice. If $(\alpha,\beta)$ is the factor pair congruences of algebra $\mathbb{A},$ prove that $(\forall \gamma\in ConA)\alpha\circ\gamma=\gamma\circ\beta.$

Answer (score 2):

**Edited Question.**
Let $\mathbb{A}$ be an algebra such that ${\rm Con}(\mathbb{A})$
is a distributive lattice. If $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a
factor pair of congruences of $\mathbb{A}$, prove that
$\alpha$ permutes with 
every $\gamma$ in ${\rm Con}(\mathbb{A})$.
(That is, $\alpha\circ\gamma=\gamma\circ\alpha$
for every $\gamma\in {\rm Con}(\mathbb{A})$.)

---

Choose any $\gamma$ in ${\rm Con}(\mathbb{A})$.
You can prove that $\alpha$ permutes with $\gamma$ in three steps.

(1) Show that $\alpha$ permutes with $\alpha\cap\gamma$.

(2) Show that $\alpha$ permutes with $\beta\cap\gamma$.

(3) Show that $\alpha$ permutes with
$(\alpha\cap\gamma)\vee(\beta\cap \gamma) = \gamma$.

For (1), use the fact that comparable equivalence relations permute.

For (2), use the facts that $\alpha$ permutes with $\beta$
and that ${\rm Con}(\mathbb{A})$ is distributive.
(Some extra details: Choose $(x,z)\in \alpha\circ (\beta\cap\gamma)$.
There is some $y$ such that $(x,y)\in\alpha$ and
$(y,z)\in\beta\cap\gamma$. Since $(x,z)\in\alpha\circ\beta=\beta\circ\alpha$
there exists $w$ such that $(x,w)\in\beta$ and $(w,z)\in\alpha$.
Now
$$(x,w)\in \beta\cap(\alpha\vee(\beta\cap\gamma))=
(\beta\cap\alpha)\vee (\beta\cap\gamma) = \beta\cap\gamma.
$$
Since $x\;(\beta\cap\gamma)\;w\;\alpha\;z$ we have 
$(x,z)\in (\beta\cap\gamma)\circ\alpha$, as desired.)

For (3), argue that if $\alpha$ permutes with two
equivalence relations, then it permutes with their join.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't true.
Just take $\gamma$ to be $\{(a,a):a\in A\}$, that gives
$$\alpha = \alpha \circ \gamma = \gamma \circ \beta = \beta,$$
which clearly doesn't hold.

Comment: And what about $\alpha \circ \gamma=\gamma \circ \alpha?$ @amrsa

Comment: I don't know. I know it doesn't hold either if you drop the congruence-distributivity assumption. If the congruence lattice is distributive, then I can't think of any counter-example. And I can't see how to prove it either...